# rewrite url based on server name on nginx

Tags: nginx

I would like to create some rewrite rule on nginx to redirect url from http to https based on server name pattern
url in format like following. I try to parse url and store number as variable between domainprefix and post Then using variable on rewrite rule. but it does not work

1:domainprefix1post.domain.com
2:domainprefix2post.domain.com
3:domainprefix3post.domain.com
...
4:domainprefix14post.domain.com
5:domainprefix15post.domain.com

try

```
server {
    listen         80;
    server_name ~^(domainprefix(?<site>[0-9]+))post.domain.com;
    rewrite        ^ https://domainprefix"$site"post.domain.com$request_uri? permanent;
}
```

result

`domainprefix11post.domain.com -> https://domainprefix%2211%22post.domain.com/`

try

```
server {
    listen         80;
    server_name ~^domainprefix(.*)post.domain.com;
    rewrite        ^ https://domainprefix$1post.domain.com$request_uri? permanent;
}
```

result

`domainprefix11post.domain.com -> https://domainprefixpost.domain.com`

Comment: Use `${site}` but place the entire URL within quotes.

Comment: ```rewrite        ^ 'https://domainprefix${site}post.domain.com'$request_uri? permanent;``` it redirect to https://%27domainprefix3post%27.domain.com/

Comment: Use: `rewrite ^ "https://domainprefix${site}post.domain.com$request_uri?" permanent;` - the quotes need to surround the entire string to be recognised as such.

Comment: thank you. it turns out i only use ${site} without any quotes. works